# Making the filter pane in pivot table sorted

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, sorting

Pivot table filtering panes lose their sort order [when data is appended to the table which is linked to the pivot table](https://superuser.com/questions/1312155/pivot-table-filter-pane-is-not-sorted).

At first, the sort order in the filtering pane looks nice:
[image: pivot table filtering pane SORTED]

But if you haven't scrolled down, you may have overlooked, that below, the sort order runs wild:
[image: pivot table filtering pane UNSORTED]

This happened, because I added more data after creating the pivot table.

**How to make this filtering pane sorted** without recreating the whole pivot table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Drag that field out of the PivotTable
2. Refresh the PivotTable
3. Drag the field back in again.

Comment: This worked! You're a genius :) It's a tedious work, though. For every field in a pivot table, when I have 10 pivot tables based on the same data table.